# How to integrate .DOCX file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I am working on app where i need to display .docx file within the app. I have a file path like ('storage/emulated/0/file1.docx'). How can i read and display it. Tried alot but not find any good solution.THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you this [pub](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_view).

I already used it in 2 of my projects. You can use it for local AND network files.

Happy coding!

Comment: but this package shows google play not suported an other thing is engine tbs load failed sometimes. i already tried it